# Парсер сайта и не создает csv файл и не возвращает найденные значения

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup, csv

Я новичок в программировании, пытаюсь написать парсер, ноон возвращает пусток значение и не создает csv файл. Не понимаю где именно ошибка или ошибки. Подсккажите, пожалуйстакак сделать так, чтобы код работал.

````
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import lxml
import re
import pdb
from time import sleep
from random import randint


header_filtered = ''
country_filtered = ''

def get_html(url):
    
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text # here I receive the whole text from the HTML page
    sleep(randint(1, 10))

def write_csv(data):
    
    with open ('possible_jobs.csv', 'a') as f:
    
       writer = csv.writer(f, csvfile, dialect='excel', **fmtparams)
       writer.writerow([data['link'],
                         data['country'],
                         data['header'],
                         data['role'],
                         data['qualification'],
                         data['compensation'],
                         data['about']])

def get_page_data(html): # this functions helps to find the necessary information
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    trs = soup.find_all('a', class_ = 'adv') #this is a job card object 
    
    for tr in trs:

        try:

            link = soup.find('a', class_ = 'adv').get('href')

        except:

            link = ''

        try:
            
            country = tr.find ('div', class_ = 'overhid').find ('div', class_="country").text.strip() #country

            
        except:
            
            country = ''



    try: #as I consider only particular countries, here I want to filter them using keywords (regular expressions)

        

        Switz = re.compile ('Switzerland', re.IGNORECASE)

        SwitzRus = re.compile ('Швейцария', re.IGNORECASE)

        Angl = re.compile ('England', re.IGNORECASE)

        AnglRus = re.compile('Англия', re.IGNORECASE)

        B = re.compile ('Great Britain', re.IGNORECASE)

        BRus = re.compile ('Великобритания', re.IGNORECASE)

        Ger = re.compile ('Germany', re.IGNORECASE)

        GerRus  = re.compile ('Германия', re.IGNORECASE)

        Nor = re.compile ('Norway', re.IGNORECASE)

        NorRus  = re.compile ('Норвегия', re.IGNORECASE)

        Swed = re.compile ('Sweden', re.IGNORECASE)

        SwedRus = re.compile ('Швеция', re.IGNORECASE)

        Den = re.compile ('Denmark', re.IGNORECASE)

        DenRus = re.compile ('Дания', re.IGNORECASE)

        if Switz.match(country):
            
                country_filtered = country
                             
        elif SwitzRus.match(country):
            
                country_filtered = country

        elif B.match(country):
            
                country_filtered = country

        elif BRus.match(country):
            
                country_filtered = country
                
        elif Ger.match(country):
            
                country_filtered = country

        elif GerRus.match(country):
            
                country_filtered = country
                
                
        elif Nor.match(country):
            
                country_filtered = country

        elif NorRus.match(country):
            
                country_filtered = country

        elif Swed.match(country):
            
                country_filtered = country

        elif SwedRus.match(country):
            
                country_filtered = country

        elif Den.match(country):
            
                country_filtered = country

        elif DenRus.match(country):
            
                country_filtered = country

    except:
            
         country_filtered = ''

        

    try:

    
           
           header = tr.find('span', class_ = 'mainl'). text. strip() #header
           
    except:
            header = ''

    try: #here I filter headers that contain keywords of interest

    

        Copywr = re.compile('Copywriter', re.IGNORECASE)

        CopywrRus = re.compile('Копирайтер', re.IGNORECASE)

        Wr = re.compile ('Writer', re.IGNORECASE)

        WrRus = re.compile ('Писатель', re.IGNORECASE)

        Cont = re.compile ('Content', re.IGNORECASE)

        ContRus = re.compile ('Контент', re.IGNORECASE)

        if Copywr.match (header):

                 header_filtered = header

        elif CopywrRus.match (header):

                 header_filtered = header
                 
        elif Wr.match(header):

                header_filtered = header

        elif WrRus.match(header):

                header_filtered = header

        elif Cont.match (header):

                header_filtered = header

        elif ContRus.match (header):

                header_filtered = header



        

    except:

            header_filtered = ''

    try:
           role = tr.find('div', class_ = 'text').text.strip()

    except:
           
           role = '' 
           


           qualification = ''

    try:
           
           compensation = tr.find ('div', class_ = 'money').text.strip()

    except:

           compensation = ''

 
    about = '' 


if country_filtered!= '' and header_filtered != '': #if the country and header don't correspond to the desired ones, such jobs won't be added to the dictionary
       
    
    data = { #here I create a dictionary which will serve as an argument for the  write_csv function
           'link': link,

           'country':country_filtered, 
           'header': header_filtered, 
           'role' : role_descr,
           'qualification' : qual_descr,
           'compensation': comp, 
           'about the company': about}
       
    write_csv(data)
    

def main():
    for i in range(0, 1251):
        url = 'https://24ru.com/?page={}'.format(str(i)) #the URL of the page I parse


    get_page_data(get_html(url))
   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()```
````

Comment: Код надо проверять на каждом этапе, а не писать простеню, а потом удивлятся, что не те результаты которые мы ожидаем. Понавешав в коде try-except вы не решили проблему, вы еще глубже залезли болото.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

country_filtered = ['США', 'Литва', 'Канада']
page = 1
page_off = 3
while page <= page_off:
    print(f'{page=}')
    url = f'https://24ru.com/?page={page}'
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    trs = soup.find_all('a', class_='adv')
    if page == 1:
        page_off = int(soup.find('div', class_='loadMore mob-gnhla')['data-pages']) #последняя страница
    page += 1

    for tr in trs:
        link =f"https://24ru.com{tr['href']}"
        header = tr.find('span', class_='mainl').text.strip()
        role = tr.find('div', class_='text').text.strip().replace('\r', '').replace('\n\n', '\n')
        try:
            compensation = tr.find('div', class_='money').text.strip()
        except:
            compensation = 'зарплата не указана'
        # тег страна может быть несколько
        country = [x.text.strip() for x in tr.findAll('div', class_="country")]
        #  фильтр по тегам страны
        flac = 0
        for ff in country:
            if ff in country_filtered: #слова для фильтра
                flac = 1
                break
        if flac:
           continue #пропускаем обьявление если сработал фильтр
        print(link)
        print(*country)
        print(header)
        print(role)
        print(compensation)
```